# Huge price difference across exchanges

Tags: exchanges

Currently on Bitfinex 1 bitcoin = $15190 while on CEX.IO 1 bitcoin = $16800. How is it possible that there's over $1500 difference? Is this just because of market forces or is Bitfinex malfunctioning?